# How to prevent Jenkins from removing double quotes in JSON parameter, to use with AWS CLI?

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, jenkins, groovy

I am running latest Jenkins in my Linux box. I have a pipeline step like below;

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {

        stage('Stage1') {
            
            steps {
                script {
                    
                    json_string = json_string.replaceAll("\\s","")
                    
                    sh("""aws opsworks update-stack --stack-id 12345-12345-12345-12345-12345 --custom-json ${json_string}""")

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`json_string` is a parameter. Suppose I am giving the JSON parameter like below;

```
{
    "key1": {
        "key11": "value11"
    },
    "key2": {
        "key21": "value21"
    }
}
```

The shell script is getting interpreted like below;

```
aws opsworks update-stack --stack-id 12345-12345-12345-12345-12345 --custom-json {'key1:{key11:value11}' 'key2{key21:value21}'}
```

The quotes as well as comma are missing. I cannot escape the JSON at the time of input, but can use something like `json_string.replace("\"","\\\"")` to manually escape.

But, if there is no comma like below;

```
{
    "key1": {
        "key11": "value11"
    }
}
```

it is works well.

How can I prevent Jenkins from removing double quotes and comma?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

that's how shell/bash interprets quotation

just try to run this from shell:

```sh
> echo {"key":"value"}
{key:value}
```

as you can see - quotes are removed

now quote the whole json with single quotes (hope you don't have it inside json)

```sh
> echo '{"key":"value"}'
{"key":"value"}
```

the simplest solution to wrap json into singlequotes:

```js
sh("""aws opsworks update-stack --stack-id ... --custom-json '${json_string}' """)
```

however it will not work if you have a singlequote inside `json_string`

ihmo the best solution is to do secondary encoding of json because shell has the same string encoding rules (usually):

```
def escaped_json = groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(json_string)
sh("""aws opsworks update-stack --stack-id ... --custom-json ${escaped_json} """)
```

`groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson` converts `{"key":"value"}` to `"{\"key\":\"value\"}"`